# Errors in installing classInt R package in Mac - gfortran not found despite installing gfortran using homebrew?

Tags: r, rstudio, gfortran, r-sf

**Error installing classInt R package on MAC OS Monterey - gfortran not found despite installation**

I was trying to install sf package in R which is dependent on classInt package. Installation of classInt throws up the following error-:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/6.1.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [classInt.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘classInt’

- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/classInt’
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/smitaprasad/Downloads/classInt_0.4-7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

I installed gfortran using homebrew .

$ which gfortran
/usr/local/bin/gfortran

any ideas on how to solve the error?
how do i get the compiler to search in the right directory ?

Searching the internet I have found following solutions that have worked for some people , but they haven't solved my problem.
I still get the same error .

1. The first was to install gfortran using this method -:

> curl -O  https://mac.r-project.org/libs-arm64/gfortran-f51f1da0-darwin20.0-arm64.tar.gz
> sudo tar fvxz gfortran-f51f1da0-darwin20.0-arm64.tar.gz -C /

2. The second was to create a  ~/.R/Makevars file with flags

   FC      = usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran

   F77     = /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran

   FLIBS   = -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib

and I tried changing the flag values in Makevars file to -:

```
FC      = /usr/local/bin/gfortran
F77     = /usr/local/bin/gfortran
FLIBS   = -L/usr/bin/gcc
                                                                                                None of the fixes worked for me . Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Dig up (or join) the r-sig-mac mailing list.  There's tons of accurate info on how & what & where to enable compiling Fortran.  Homebrew is low on the list of good ways to do it.

Comment: Hi I tried searching for a solution on r-sig-mac .So far I have found two fixes that were suggested but both didn't solve my issue .